# Google Analytics Core Reporting API にてサイトごとのリファラーを取得したい

Tags: api

Google Analytics Core Reporting API についての質問です。

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#cats=traffic_sources
↑のページを見ていて、
ga:fullReferrer の ディメンションは取得できたのですが、リファラーのドメインだけ取得することは可能でしょうか？
・現状
　url => pv
　sample.com/archives/aaa.html => 1
　sample.com/archives/bbb.html => 3
・こうしたい
　url => pv
　sample.com => 4

よろしくお願いします

Answer (score 0, accepted):

手元のサンプルが少ないので間違っていたらすみません。

ga:source では期待する結果を得られませんでしょうか。

Comment: 試してみます、ありがとうございます！

Comment: うまくいきました！
助かりましたm(__)m